# Using `ifthenelse` to combine two related functions into one

Tags: conditionals, datatool, xifthen

This question is based on Peter Grill's answer to ["Table including
rows of a master table".](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61021/3406).

The function `PrintDTLTable` was in Peter's original answer. I
wanted a version that would run over all rows, so I motified this
slightly to `PrintDTLTableDefault`, which does not have a row id
argument. Both `PrintDTLTable` and `PrintDTLTableDefault` work as expected.

I think it makes more sense to combine these into a single
function, so I tried using `ifthenelse` and this gave
`PrintDTLTableCombined`. This gives the error

```
ERROR: Argument of \isempty has an extra }.
```

I don't see any obvious syntax or usage errors. As usual with LaTeX,
the error could easily be something completely unrelated to the error message.
I don't have to use `ifthenelse`; something else would be fine.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\newcommand{\colhead}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\bfseries}l}{#1}}
\newcounter{tabenum}\setcounter{tabenum}{0}
\newcommand{\nextnuml}[1]{\refstepcounter{tabenum}\thetabenum.\label{#1}}

\begin{filecontents*}{foo.dat}
  Hammer001,   Hammer,    1 ,  0 , 1 , 10 , 1 , \multirow{2}{2in}{light (add some words here to wrap around)}\\
  Hammer002,   Hammer,    2 ,  0 , 1 , 10 , 1 , heavy
  Hammer003,   Hammer,    3 ,  0 , 1 , 10 , 1 , really heavy
  Longsword001,Longsword, 1 , -1 , 2 , 75 , 2 , one-handed
  Longsword002,Longsword, 2 , -1 , 2 , 75 , 2 , two-handed
  Longsword003,Longsword, 3 , -1 , 2 , 75 , 2 , three-handed
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand{\PrintDTLTable}[2]{%
  % #1 = database to search
  % #2 = list of rowIDs
  \begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c p{3.0cm}}
    & \colhead{Label} & \colhead{Cost} & \colhead{Weight} & \colhead{PropA} & \colhead{PropB} & \colhead{PropC} & \colhead{Description}\\\hline
    \DTLforeach[\DTLisSubString{#2}{\RowID}]{#1}{%
      \RowID=RowID,%
      \Label=Label,%
      \Cost=Cost,%
      \Weight=Weight,%
      \PropA=PropA,%
      \PropB=PropB,%
      \PropC=PropC,%
      \Description=Description%
    }{%
      \nextnuml{\RowID} & \Label &\Cost & \Weight & \PropA & \PropB & \PropC & \Description \\
    }%
  \end{tabular}
}%

\newcommand{\PrintDTLTableDefault}[1]{%
  % #1 = database to search
  \begin{longtable}{c c c c c c c p{3.0cm}}
    & \colhead{Label} & \colhead{Cost} & \colhead{Weight} & \colhead{PropA} & \colhead{PropB} & \colhead{PropC} & \colhead{Description}\\\hline
    \DTLforeach[\boolean{true}]
    {#1}{%
      \RowID=RowID,%
      \Label=Label,%
      \Cost=Cost,%
      \Weight=Weight,%
      \PropA=PropA,%
      \PropB=PropB,%
      \PropC=PropC,%
      \Description=Description%
    }{%
      \nextnuml{\RowID} & \Label &\Cost & \Weight & \PropA & \PropB & \PropC & \Description \\
    }%
  \end{longtable}
}%

\newcommand{\PrintDTLTableCombined}[2][]{%
 % #1 = list of rowIDs
 % #2 = database to search
  \begin{longtable}{c c c c c c c p{3.0cm}}
    & \colhead{Label} & \colhead{Cost} & \colhead{Weight} & \colhead{PropA} & \colhead{PropB} & \colhead{PropC} & \colhead{Description}\\\hline
    \DTLforeach
    [\ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{\boolean{true}}{\DTLisSubString{#1}{\RowID}}]
    {#2}{%
      \RowID=RowID,%
      \Label=Label,%
      \Cost=Cost,%
      \Weight=Weight,%
      \PropA=PropA,%
      \PropB=PropB,%
      \PropC=PropC,%
      \Description=Description%
    }{%
      \nextnuml{\RowID} & \Label &\Cost & \Weight & \PropA & \PropB & \PropC & \Description \\
    }%
  \end{longtable}
}%

\begin{document}
% \DTLsetseparator{&}% Define separator of the data
\DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={RowID,Label,Cost,Weight,PropA,PropB,PropC,Description}]{myDB}{foo.dat}

%\PrintDTLTable{myDB}{Hammer001,Hammer003,Longsword003}
%\PrintDTLTableDefault{myDB}
\PrintDTLTableCombined{myDB}

This is a reference to ~\ref{Hammer003}.

\end{document}
```

UPDATE: @Werner's macro works for me. However, I'm still would like to know what made my attempt fail; maybe it would be instructive. LaTeX is frustrating for a beginner, partly because it frequently seems impossible to debug for a non-expert.

Comment: I can't see why using `\multirow` and not the simpler `\multicolumn{1}{p{2in}}{...}`

Comment: @egreg: The `\multirow` thing is a detail I should probably have left out. I've thought of using p, but why do I need to wrap it in `\multicolumn{1}`?

Comment: If it's an "exceptional" cell, you need `\multicolumn{1}` for overriding the standard alignment for the column. Or just specify the whole column as `p{2in}`. Note that with the `\multicolumn` approach, the rules automatically take care of the width, which doesn't happen with `\multirow`.

Comment: @FaheemMitha: I've added an explanation of the problem you ran into.

Answer (score 4):

It works when you perform the "check for empty arguments" using

```
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/308/5764
\makeatletter
\def\ifemptyarg#1{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax % H. Oberdiek
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi}
\makeatother
```

instead of the [`xifthen`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xifthen) `\ifthenelse`:

```
\newcommand{\PrintDTLTableCombined}[2][]{%
 % #1 = list of rowIDs
 % #2 = database to search
  \begin{longtable}{c c c c c c c p{3.0cm}}
    & \colhead{Label} & \colhead{Cost} & \colhead{Weight} & \colhead{PropA} & \colhead{PropB} & \colhead{PropC} & \colhead{Description}\\\hline

    \DTLforeach
    [\ifemptyarg{#1}{\boolean{true}}{\DTLisSubString{#1}{\RowID}}]
    {#2}{%
      \RowID=RowID,%
      \Label=Label,%
      \Cost=Cost,%
      \Weight=Weight,%
      \PropA=PropA,%
      \PropB=PropB,%
      \PropC=PropC,%
      \Description=Description%
    }{%
      \nextnuml{\RowID} & \Label &\Cost & \Weight & \PropA & \PropB & \PropC & \Description \\
    }%
  \end{longtable}
}%
```

Checking for an empty argument is sometimes problematic, since some uses could require an assignment, which is not allowed.

---

An analysis of *why* your approach does not work stems from how [`datatool`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool) evaluates conditionals. Inside the bowels of `\DTLforeach[#1]{#2}{#3}{#4}` is a test

```
\ifthenelse{#1}{<true>}{<false>}
```

The [`datatool`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool) [user guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/datatool/datatool-user.pdf) supports this (section **5.4 Iterating Through a Database**, p 50):

> ```
> \DTLforeach[<condition>]{<db name>}{<assign list>}{<text>}
> ```
>
> The optional argument `<condition>` is a condition in the form allowed
>   by `\ifthenelse`. This includes the commands provided by the `ifthen`
>   package (such as `\not`, `\and`, `\or`), as well as the commands described
>   in section 2.2. The default value of `<condition>` is `\boolean{true}`.

So, effectively what you're trying to implement is a nested conditional that resembles

```
\ifthenelse{\ifthenelse{<condition>}{<trueA>}{<falseA>}}{<trueB>}{<falseB>}
```

A minimal example that replicates the problem is given by

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xifthen}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xifthen
\begin{document}
\ifthenelse{\ifthenelse{\boolean{true}}{\boolean{true}}{\boolean{false}}}{A}{B}
\end{document}
```

While the above should (logically) yield `A` as output (since the nested condition should yield `\boolean{true}`, which evaluated is true and should output `A`), you receive the error

```
! Argument of \boolean has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.4 ...an{true}}{\boolean{true}}{\boolean{false}}}
                                                  {A}{B}
```

There's no other way around it but to use a different method for deriving a result to condition on, since you are using the condition to decide whether/not to print a row. That is, you can't evaluate the condition outside `\DTLforeach`.

Comment: Instead of `ifthen`, I suggest to use `etoolbox`: `\ifstrempty{string}{<case for empty>}{<case for non empty>}`

Comment: @egreg The `\ifstrempty` works too, thanks.