# Automatically creating a table from datatool using references in the text

Tags: tables, citing, datatool

This question is based on Peter Grill's answer to ["Table including
rows of a master
table".](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61021/3406).

The function `\PrintDTLTable` takes an optional list of rowIDs
(first row of the data file) as its first argument, and makes a
table containing only those rows. The rowIDs are also used as
labels.

BibTeX is usually used so that it only lists those papers that are
cited in the bibligraphy. I don't know how this mechanism works, but
I was wondering if can be adapted to this situation. I.e., if I
reference some rows by label in the text, then is there some way to
automatically generate a table containing only the rows
corresponding to the labels appearing in the text?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\newcommand{\colhead}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\bfseries}l}{#1}}
\newcounter{tabenum}\setcounter{tabenum}{0}
\newcommand{\nextnuml}[1]{\refstepcounter{tabenum}\thetabenum.\label{#1}}

\begin{filecontents*}{foo.dat}
  Hammer001,   Hammer,    1 ,  0 , 1 , 10 , 1 , \multirow{2}{2in}{light (add some words here to wrap around)}\\
  Hammer002,   Hammer,    2 ,  0 , 1 , 10 , 1 , heavy
  Hammer003,   Hammer,    3 ,  0 , 1 , 10 , 1 , really heavy
  Longsword001,Longsword, 1 , -1 , 2 , 75 , 2 , one-handed
  Longsword002,Longsword, 2 , -1 , 2 , 75 , 2 , two-handed
  Longsword003,Longsword, 3 , -1 , 2 , 75 , 2 , three-handed
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand{\PrintDTLTable}[2][]{%
 % #1 = list of rowIDs
 % #2 = database to search
  \begin{longtable}{l l l l l l l l}
    % & \colhead{Date} & \colhead{From} & \colhead{To} & \colhead{Email} & \colhead{Subject}\\\hlin
    & \colhead{Label} & \colhead{Cost} & \colhead{Weight} & \colhead{PropA} & \colhead{PropB} & \colhead{PropC} & \colhead{Description}\\\hline
    \DTLforeach
    [\ifblank{#1}{\boolean{true}}{\DTLisSubString{#1}{\RowID}}]
    {#2}{%
      \RowID=RowID,%
      \Label=Label,%
      \Cost=Cost,%
      \Weight=Weight,%
      \PropA=PropA,%
      \PropB=PropB,%
      \PropC=PropC,%
      \Description=Description%
     }{%
       \nextnuml{\RowID} & \Label &\Cost & \Weight & \PropA & \PropB & \PropC & \Description \\
    }%
    \end{longtable}
}%

\begin{document}
% \DTLsetseparator{&}% Define separator of the data
\DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={RowID,Label,Cost,Weight,PropA,PropB,PropC,Description}]{myDB}{foo.dat}

% \DTLdisplaydb{myDB}% Useful for debugging.

\PrintDTLTable[Hammer001,Hammer003,Longsword003]{myDB}
\PrintDTLTable{myDB}

This is a reference to ~\ref{Hammer003}.

\end{document}
```

The tables produced by the code should be as follows: In the case of

```
\PrintDTLTable[Hammer001,Hammer003,Longsword003]{myDB}
```

the table by default consists of the three rows

```
Hammer001,Hammer003,Longsword003
```

Since the only reference is to `Hammer003`, the table produced should only contain the `Hammer003` row.

Similarly, in the case of `\PrintDTLTable{myDB}`, the table by default consists of all 6 rows. Again, since the only reference is to `Hammer003`, the table produced should only contain the `Hammer003` row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.dat}
  Hammer001,   Hammer,    1 ,  0 , 1 , 10 , 1 , light (add some words here to wrap around)
  Hammer002,   Hammer,    2 ,  0 , 1 , 10 , 1 , heavy
  Hammer003,   Hammer,    3 ,  0 , 1 , 10 , 1 , really heavy
  Longsword001,Longsword, 1 , -1 , 2 , 75 , 2 , one-handed
  Longsword002,Longsword, 2 , -1 , 2 , 75 , 2 , two-handed
  Longsword003,Longsword, 3 , -1 , 2 , 75 , 2 , three-handed
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\colhead}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\bfseries}l}{#1}}
\newcounter{tabenum}\setcounter{tabenum}{0}
\newcommand{\nextnuml}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{tabenum}\thetabenum.\label{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\PrintDTLTable}[2][]{%
 % #1 = list of rowIDs
 % #2 = database to search
  \begin{longtable}{l l l l l l l m{2in}}
  & \colhead{Label} & \colhead{Cost} & \colhead{Weight} &
    \colhead{PropA} & \colhead{PropB} & \colhead{PropC} & \colhead{Description}\\
  \hline
  \DTLforeach
    [%
     \(\equal{#1}{}\AND\DTLisSubString{\ReferencedIDs}{\RowID}\)
     \OR
     \(\DTLisSubString{#1}{\RowID}\AND\DTLisSubString{\ReferencedIDs}{\RowID}\)%
    ]
    {#2}{%
      \RowID=RowID,%
      \Label=Label,%
      \Cost=Cost,%
      \Weight=Weight,%
      \PropA=PropA,%
      \PropB=PropB,%
      \PropC=PropC,%
      \Description=Description%
     }{%
       \nextnuml{\RowID} & \Label &\Cost & \Weight & \PropA & \PropB & \PropC & \Description \\
    }%
    \end{longtable}
}

\makeatletter
\let\oldref\ref
\def\ref#1{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{%
    \string\gappto\string\ReferencedIDs{#1,}%
  }%
  \oldref{#1}%
}
\def\ReferencedIDs{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

% \DTLsetseparator{&}% Define separator of the data
\DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={RowID,Label,Cost,Weight,PropA,PropB,PropC,Description}]{myDB}{\jobname.dat}

% \DTLdisplaydb{myDB}% Useful for debugging.

\PrintDTLTable[Hammer001,Hammer003,Longsword003]{myDB}

\PrintDTLTable[Hammer002,Longsword002]{myDB}

This is a reference to ~\ref{Hammer003}.

This is a reference to ~\ref{Longsword002}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

The macro `\ref` is redefined to write in the `.aux` file also

```
\gappto\ReferencedIDs{Hammer003,}
\gappto\ReferencedIDs{Longsword002,}
```

assuming that `\ref{Hammer003}` and `\ref{Longsword002}` appear in the text.

The macro `\ReferencedIDs` is initialized to empty at the start of the job. At the next run, when LaTeX reads the `.aux` file, it will see those instructions, so at begin document the value of `\ReferencedIDs` would be equivalent to having said

```
\def\ReferencedIDs{Hammer003,Longsword002,}
```

because of how `\gappto` works.

When `\DTLforeach` is called, we check the optional argument. If it's empty, the current ID is matched only with `\ReferencedIDs`. Otherwise, the current ID is matched against both the optional argument and `\ReferencedIDs`; if the current ID is present in both lists, the row is printed, otherwise it's omitted.

Answer (score 9):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\makeatletter
\let\oldref\ref
\def\ref#1{\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\expandafter\gdef\noexpand\csname REF:#1\string\endcsname{}}%
\oldref{#1}}


\def\zz#1#2{\noalign{%
\expandafter\ifx\csname REF:#1\endcsname\@empty
\def\@currentlabel{#2}\label{#1}%
\else
\aftergroup\zzapline
\fi}#2}

\long\def\zzapline#1\\{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

  \begin{longtable}{l l l l l l p{2in}}
  \zz{Hammer001}{Hammer}&    1 &  0 & 1 & 10 & 1 & light (add some words here to wrap around)\\
   \zz{Hammer002}{Hammer}&    2 &  0 & 1 & 10 & 1 & heavy\\
  \zz{Hammer003}{Hammer}&    3 &  0 & 1 & 10 & 1 & really heavy\\
  \zz{Longsword001}{Longsword}& 1 & -1 & 2 & 75 & 2 & one-handed\\
  \zz{Longsword002}{Longsword}& 2 & -1 & 2 & 75 & 2 & two-handed\\
  \zz{Longsword003}{Longsword}& 3 & -1 & 2 & 75 & 2 & three-handed\\% don't miss this out
\end{longtable}


This is a reference to ~\ref{Hammer003} or  ~\ref{Longsword002}.

\end{document}
```