# Creating a list of labels automatically for use by datatool

Tags: tables, datatool

The following is partly a followup to an earlier question, and Enrico's answer, as given in
[Automatically creating a table from datatool using references in the text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/219597/3406).

The method outlined there works, but is rather slow. It occured to me that one way of improving the speed might be to write the row label information explicitly in a separate file. Consider the example below.

The line

```
\PrintDocTable{dDB}{Documents}
```

prints all rows of the table. However, I have the option of explicitly listing the rows I want to print, with

```
\PrintDocTable[2014.11.14,2013.10.05.powai]{dDB}{Documents}
```

As long as the rows listed as the same as those referenced, there is no problem. However, keeping these in sync with the references is work.

I think it should be possible to have the `\ref` macro write a list of the labels automatically in a separate file from the aux file, say `example.lab`, and then include that file directly inside the `[]` argument to `\PrintDocTable`. Something like this:

```
\PrintDocTable[\include{example.lab}]{dDB}{Documents}
```

where `example.lab` in this case would contain the text "2014.11.14,2013.10.05.powai". Is this feasible, and if so, how would I modify the `\ref` macro?

```
###########################################
example.tex
###########################################
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage[verbose]{datatool}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{url}
\newcounter{tabenum}\setcounter{tabenum}{0}
\newcommand{\colhead}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\bfseries}l}{#1}}
\newcommand{\nextnuml}[1]{\refstepcounter{tabenum}\thetabenum.\label{#1}}
\makeatletter
\let\oldref\ref
\def\ref#1{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{%
    \string\gappto\string\ReferencedIDs{#1,}%
  }%
  \oldref{#1}%
}
\def\ReferencedIDs{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{fouriernc}
\address{Some Address\\ Some Place\\Email: foo@bar.com}
\signature{(Somebody)}
\newcommand*{\checkmissing}[1]{\DTLifnull{#1}{}{#1}}

\newcommand{\PrintDocTable}[3][]{%
 % #1 = list of rowIDs
 % #2 = database to search
 % #3 =caption
  \begin{longtable}{r l p{1.5in} c c p{2.5in}}
    \caption{#3}\\
   & \colhead{Date} & \colhead{Filename} & \colhead{From} & \colhead{To} & \colhead{Subject}\\\hline\endhead
    \DTLforeach
    [\ifblank{#1}{\boolean{true}}{\DTLisSubString{#1}{\RowID}}]
    {#2}{%
      \RowID=RowID,%
      \Date=Date,%
      \Filename=Filename,%
      \From=From,%
      \To=To,%
      \Subject=Subject%
    }{%
      \nextnuml{\RowID} & \Date & {\bfseries\expandafter\url\expandafter{\Filename} } & \checkmissing{\From} & \checkmissing{\To} & \Subject \\
    }%
  \end{longtable}
}%

\begin{filecontents*}{doc.csv}
  familytree,26 Feb 2014,something.txt,subject
  2013.10.05.kanjur,05 Oct 2013,something.txt,subject
  2013.10.05.powai,05 Oct 2013,something.txt,subject
  2014.11.14,14 Nov 2014,something.txt,FROM,TO,,subject
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\def\today{9th January, 2014}
\begin{letter}{
    Someone\\
    Somewhere\\
    Subject: Some stuff
}

  \opening{Dear Someone}

  Here are some refs - [\ref{2014.11.14}]. [\ref{2013.10.05.powai}].

\closing{Yours Sincerely,}

\DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={RowID,Date,Filename,From,To,Email,Subject}]{dDB}{doc.csv}
%\PrintDocTable{dDB}{Documents}
\PrintDocTable[2014.11.14,2013.10.05.powai]{dDB}{Documents}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage[verbose]{datatool}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{url}
\newcounter{tabenum}\setcounter{tabenum}{0}
\newcommand{\colhead}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\bfseries}l}{#1}}
\newcommand{\nextnuml}[1]{\refstepcounter{tabenum}\thetabenum.\label{#1}}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\providecommand\ReferencedIDs{}}
\AtEndDocument{\immediate\write\@auxout{\gdef\string\ReferencedIDs{\ReferencedIDs}}}
\let\oldref\ref
\def\ref#1{%
  \g@addto@macro\ReferencedIDs{,#1}%
  \oldref{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{fouriernc}
\address{Some Address\\ Some Place\\Email: foo@bar.com}
\signature{(Somebody)}
\newcommand*{\checkmissing}[1]{\DTLifnull{#1}{}{#1}}

\newcommand{\PrintDocTable}[3][]{%
 % #1 = list of rowIDs
 % #2 = database to search
 % #3 =caption
  \begin{longtable}{r l p{1.5in} c c p{2.5in}}
    \caption{#3}\\
   & \colhead{Date} & \colhead{Filename} & \colhead{From} & \colhead{To} & \colhead{Subject}\\\hline\endhead
    \DTLforeach
    [\ifblank{#1}{\boolean{true}}{\DTLisSubString{#1}{\RowID}}]
    {#2}{%
      \RowID=RowID,%
      \Date=Date,%
      \Filename=Filename,%
      \From=From,%
      \To=To,%
      \Subject=Subject%
    }{%
      \nextnuml{\RowID} & \Date & {\bfseries\expandafter\url\expandafter{\Filename} } & \checkmissing{\From} & \checkmissing{\To} & \Subject \\
    }%
  \end{longtable}
}%

\begin{filecontents*}{doc.csv}
  familytree,26 Feb 2014,something.txt,subject
  2013.10.05.kanjur,05 Oct 2013,something.txt,subject
  2013.10.05.powai,05 Oct 2013,something.txt,subject
  2014.11.14,14 Nov 2014,something.txt,FROM,TO,,subject
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\def\today{9th January, 2014}
\begin{letter}{
    Someone\\
    Somewhere\\
    Subject: Some stuff
}

  \opening{Dear Someone}

  Here are some refs - [\ref{2014.11.14}]. [\ref{2013.10.05.powai}].

\closing{Yours Sincerely,}

\DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={RowID,Date,Filename,From,To,Email,Subject}]{dDB}{doc.csv}
%\PrintDocTable{dDB}{Documents}

\PrintDocTable[\ReferencedIDs]{dDB}{Documents}\renewcommand\ReferencedIDs{}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```