# Difference in compilation time between two slightly different versions

Tags: compiling, datatool, performance

This question is a byproduct of earlier questions:
[Creating a list of labels automatically for use by datatool](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/227002/3406)
and
[Automatically creating a table from datatool using references in the text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/153335/3406).

Here is a LaTeX file using datatool. There are two slightly different versions of this: I'll call these VERSION 1 and VERSION 2. VERSION 1 is due to egreg, VERSION 2 is due to DavidCarlisle.

For reasons that are not at all clear to me, VERSION 2 is much slower to compile than VERSION 1. VERSION 1 consistently takes around 10 seconds. VERSION 2 varies, but takes at least twice that, upwards of 20 seconds. Superficially the two versions look very similar.

The different VERSIONs correspond to two blocks in the following file, each starting with `\makeatletter` and `makeatother`.

When testing, remember to remove the aux file when switching versions.

What is causing this significant difference in compilation speed?

```
#########################################################################

\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage[verbose]{datatool}
\usepackage{datagidx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{url}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.10in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.10in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.3in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.2in}
\textheight=8.8in
\textwidth=6.7in
\newcounter{tabenum}\setcounter{tabenum}{0}
\newcommand{\colhead}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\bfseries}l}{#1}}
\newcommand{\nextnuml}[1]{\refstepcounter{tabenum}\thetabenum.\label{#1}}

% VERSION 1

\makeatletter
\let\oldref\ref
\def\ref#1{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{%
    \string\gappto\string\ReferencedIDs{#1,}%
  }%
  \oldref{#1}%
}
\def\ReferencedIDs{}
\makeatother

% VERSION 2

% \makeatletter
% \AtBeginDocument{\providecommand\ReferencedIDs{}}
% \AtEndDocument{\immediate\write\@auxout{\gdef\string\ReferencedIDs{\ReferencedIDs}}}
% \let\oldref\ref
% \def\ref#1{%
%   \g@addto@macro\ReferencedIDs{,#1}%
%   \oldref{#1}%
% }
% \makeatother

\usepackage{fouriernc}
\address{Some Address\\ Some Place\\Email: foo@bar.com}
\signature{(Somebody)}
\newcommand*{\checkmissing}[1]{\DTLifnull{#1}{}{#1}}

\newcommand{\PrintDocTableParekh}[3][]{%
 % #1 = list of rowIDs
 % #2 = database to search
 % #3 =caption
  \begin{longtable}{r l p{1.5in} c c p{2.5in}}
    \caption{#3}\\
   & \colhead{Date} & \colhead{Filename} & \colhead{From} & \colhead{To} & \colhead{Subject}\\\hline\endhead
    \DTLforeach
    [\ifblank{#1}{\boolean{true}}{\DTLisSubString{#1}{\RowID}}]
    % [%
    % \(%
    % \equal{#1}{}\AND\DTLisSubString{\ReferencedIDs}{\RowID}%
    % \)%
    % \OR\(
    % \DTLisSubString{#1}{\RowID}\AND\DTLisSubString{\ReferencedIDs}{\RowID}%
    % \)%
    % ]
    {#2}{%
      \RowID=RowID,%
      \Date=Date,%
      \Filename=Filename,%
      \From=From,%
      \To=To,%
      \Subject=Subject%
    }{%
      \nextnuml{\RowID} & \Date & {\bfseries\expandafter\url\expandafter{\Filename} } & \checkmissing{\From} & \checkmissing{\To} & \Subject \\
    }%
  \end{longtable}
}%

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\AddToTable}[2]{%
\DTLforeach*{#2}{\newDBRowID=RowID,\newDBDate=Date,\newDBFilename=Filename,\newDBFrom=From,\newDBTo=To,\newDBSubject=Subject}{
  \DTLnewrow{#1}
  {\let\DTLnewdbentry\relax % Avoid expansion of \DTLnewdbentry when using \protected@xdef below
   \protected@xdef\insertnewdbentry{%
     \DTLnewdbentry{#1}{RowID}{\newDBRowID}%
     \DTLnewdbentry{#1}{Date}{\newDBDate}%
     \DTLnewdbentry{#1}{Filename}{\newDBFilename}%
     \DTLnewdbentry{#1}{From}{\newDBFrom}%
     \DTLnewdbentry{#1}{To}{\newDBTo}%
     \DTLnewdbentry{#1}{Subject}{\newDBSubject}%
  }}\insertnewdbentry
}}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents*}{newa.csv}
smyt.bs.ie,Mar 2004-2013 (incl.),something.txt,,,,subject
ct.bs.ie,Mar 2004-2013 (incl.),something.txt,,,,subject
cf.bs.ie,Mar 2004-2013 (incl.),something.txt,,,,subject
ismail.bs.ie,Mar 2004-2013 (incl.),something.txt,,,,subject
mh.bs.ie,Mar 2004-2013 (incl.),something.txt,,,,subject
smyt.it,2007-2013,something.txt,,,,subject
ismail.it,2008-2013,something.txt,,,,subject
familytree,26 Feb 2014,something.txt,,,,subject
trusts,26 Feb 2014,something.txt,,,,subject
1952.02.19,19 Feb 1952,something.txt,,,,subject
1994.03.26,26 Mar 1994,something.txt,,,,subject
1998.09.14,14 Sep 1998,something.txt,FROM,TO,,subject
1998.09.16,16 Sep 1998,something.txt,FROM,TO,,subject
2001.05.23,23 May 2001,something.txt,FROM,TO,,subject
2007.06.10,10 Jun 2007,something.txt,FROM,TO,,subject
2010.11.04,04 Nov 2010,something.txt,,,,subject
2011.05.09,09 May 2011,something.txt,FROM,TO,Y,subject
2011.09.09.slm,09 Sep 2011,something.txt,FROM,TO,Y,subject
2011.09.26.fm,26 Sep 2011,something.txt,FROM,TO,Y,subject
2011.09.26.slm,26 Sep 2011,something.txt,FROM,TO,Y,subject
2011.09.26.zhm,26 Sep 2011,something.txt,FROM,TO,,subject
2011.11.21.slm,21 Nov 2011,something.txt,FROM,TO,Y,subject
2011.11.21.fm,21 Nov 2011,something.txt,FROM,TO,Y,subject
2011.11.22,22 Nov 2011,something.txt,FROM,TO,Y,subject
2011.11.23,23 Nov 2011,something.txt,FROM,TO,Y,subject
2012.01.25,25 Jan 2012 (?),something.txt,FROM,TO,,subject
2012.12.07,07 Dec 2012,something.txt,FROM,TO,,subject
2013.01.14,14 Jan 2013,something.txt,FROM,TO,,subject
2013.08.29,29 Aug 2013,something.txt,FROM,TO,Y,subject
2013.09.09.fm,09 Sep 2013,something.txt,FROM,TO,Y,subject
2013.09.09.rm,09 Sep 2013,something.txt,FROM,TO,Y,subject
2013.09.10.slm,10 Sep 2013,something.txt,FROM,TO,Y,subject
2013.09.10.fm,10 Sep 2013,something.txt,FROM,TO,Y,subject
2013.09.10.slm2,10 Sep 2013,something.txt,FROM,TO,,subject
2013.09.11.slm1,11 Sep 2013,something.txt,FROM,TO,Y,subject
2013.09.11.fm,11 Sep 2013,something.txt,FROM,TO,Y,subject
2013.09.11.slm2,11 Sep 2013,something.txt,FROM,TO,Y,subject
2013.09.16,16 Sep 2013,something.txt,FROM,TO,,subject
2013.09.17,17 Sep 2013,something.txt,FROM,TO,,subject
2013.09.23,23 Sep 2013,something.txt,FROM,TO,,subject
2013.10.05.powai,05 Oct 2013,something.txt,,,,subject
2013.10.05.kanjur,05 Oct 2013,something.txt,,,,subject
2013.10.06,06 Oct 2013,something.txt,FROM,TO,,subject
2013.10.14.kma,14 Oct 2013,something.txt,FROM,TO,,subject
2013.10.14.ks,14 Oct 2013,something.txt,FROM,TO,,subject
2013.10.16,16 Oct 2013,something.txt,FROM,TO,,subject
2013.10.17,17 Oct 2013,something.txt,FROM,TO,,subject
2013.10.18,18 Oct 2013,something.txt,FROM,TO,,subject
2013.10.22,22 Oct 2013,something.txt,FROM,TO,,subject
2013.10.23,23 Oct 2013,something.txt,FROM,TO,,subject
2013.10.24,24 Oct 2013,something.txt,FROM,TO,,subject
2013.10.25.zhm,25 Oct 2013,something.txt,FROM,TO,,subject
2013.10.25.fm1,25 Oct 2013,something.txt,FROM,TO,Y,subject
2013.10.25.rm1,25 Oct 2013,something.txt,FROM,TO,Y,subject
2013.10.25.fm2,25 Oct 2013,something.txt,FROM,TO,Y,subject
2013.10.25.rm2,25 Oct 2013,something.txt,FROM,TO,Y,subject
2013.10.28,28 Oct 2013,something.txt,FROM,TO,,subject
2013.10.28.zhm,28 Oct 2013,something.txt,,,,subject
2013.10.30,30 Oct 2013,something.txt,FROM,TO,,subject
2013.11.11,11 Nov 2013,something.txt,FROM,TO,,subject
2013.11.12,12 Nov 2013,something.txt,FROM,TO,,subject
2013.11.13,13 Nov 2013,something.txt,FROM,TO,,subject
2013.11.25,25 Nov 2013,something.txt,FROM,TO,,subject
2013.12.05.ta,05 Dec 2013,something.txt,FROM,TO,,subject
2013.12.05.slm,05 Dec 2013,something.txt,FROM,TO,,subject
2014.01.15,15 Jan 2014,something.txt,FROM,TO,,subject
2014.02.24,24 Feb 2014,something.txt,FROM,TO,,subject
2014.02.26,26 Feb 2014,something.txt,,,,subject
2014.04.02,02 Apr 2014,something.txt,FROM,TO,,subject
2014.04.10,10 Apr 2014,something.txt,FROM,TO,,subject
2014.04.15,15 Apr 2014,something.txt,FROM,TO,,subject
2014.07.18.tm,18 Jul 2014,something.txt,FROM,TO,,subject
2014.07.18.ta,18 Jul 2014,something.txt,FROM,TO,,subject
2014.07.24,24 Jul 2014,something.txt,FROM,TO,,subject
2014.09.05.tm,05 Sep 2014,something.txt,FROM,TO,,subject
2014.09.05.ta,05 Sep 2014,something.txt,FROM,TO,,subject
2014.09.05.slm,05 Sep 2014,something.txt,FROM,TO,,subject
2014.10.17,17 Oct 2014,something.txt,FROM,TO,,subject
2014.11.12.tm,12 Nov 2014,something.txt,FROM,TO,,subject
2014.11.14,14 Nov 2014,something.txt,FROM,TO,,subject
2014.11.17,17 Nov 2014,something.txt,FROM,TO,,subject
2015.01.06,06 Jan 2015,something.txt,FROM,TO,,subject
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\def\today{9th January, 2014}
\begin{letter}{
    Someone\\
    Somewhere\\
    Subject: Some stuff
}

  \opening{Dear Someone}

  \lipsum[1]. Here is a ref - [\ref{2014.11.14}].

  \lipsum[2]. Here is a ref - [\ref{2014.11.14}].

  \lipsum[3] Here is a ref - [\ref{2014.11.17}].

  \lipsum[4]


  \lipsum[5] Here is a ref - [\ref{2014.11.14}].

  \lipsum[6] Here is a ref - [\ref{2014.07.18.tm}].

  \lipsum[7]

  \lipsum[8] Here is a ref - [\ref{2014.11.12.tm}].

  \lipsum[9]. See references
    ~[\ref{2013.10.05.kanjur}], [\ref{2013.10.05.powai}].
    [\ref{2013.10.06}], [\ref{2013.10.28.zhm}],
    [\ref{2013.10.17}], [\ref{2013.10.22}],

    \lipsum[10]. See references
    [\ref{2013.10.14.ks}], [\ref{2013.10.06}]
    [\ref{2013.10.17}], [\ref{2013.10.22}], [\ref{2013.10.24}],

    \lipsum[10]. See references
    [\ref{2013.10.28}], [\ref{2013.10.30}]

    \lipsum[10]. See references [\ref{2013.11.11}]

    \lipsum[11]. See references [\ref{2014.09.05.tm}]

    \lipsum[12]. See references
    [\ref{2014.07.18.tm}] [\ref{2014.11.12.tm}]

   \lipsum[13]. See references
    [\ref{2014.11.17}], [\ref{2015.01.06}], [\ref{2015.01.06}]

\closing{Yours Sincerely,}

\DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={RowID,Date,Filename,From,To,Email,Subject}]{newaDB}{newa.csv}
\PrintDocTableParekh[\ReferencedIDs]{newaDB}{Documents}\renewcommand\ReferencedIDs{}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to clear the list but it's inside the group from `letter` so replace

```
\renewcommand\ReferencedIDs{}
```

by

```
\gdef\ReferencedIDs{}
```

then the times are the same

Comment: Yes, this works, but I don't understand the point at all. Can you elaborate, please? In particular, what does 
"it's inside the group from letter" mean? What is "it", and what group? I assume "letter" refers to the letter class.

Comment: compare the aux file after several runs, if you only locally clear it (with my version) the list gets longer and longer every time, I mean the resetting to `{}` is inside the local group from `letter` not the class the environment alll environments (except `document`) are a group like `{...}`

Comment: Yes, I see, You mean the `\renewcommand\ReferencedIDs{}` isn't actually resetting the `\renewcommand\ReferencedIDs{}` because it is only redefining it locally? So there is some kind of namespace in effect here?

Comment: @FaheemMitha not really a namespace just local scope if you go `{\renewcommand\foo{}}` then it has no effect as the value is restored at the `}`

Comment: So, this raises two issues. First, the timing is obviously very sensitive to the length of `\ReferencedIDs`. This in turn suggests that the macro `\DTLisSubString` is very slow. However, since all this macro does is do a substring check, it should be possible to replace it with something that is not so slow. Second, neither of these methods ensure that the set of strings in `\ReferencedIDs` is unique, which presumably further slows down the compilation time. Should I post these issues as a separate question?

Comment: (from the Datatool manual), `\DTLisSubString{hstringi}{hsubstringi}`
This checks if hsubstringi is contained in hstringi

Comment: Possibly. I haven't looked at the code there to see if it could be improved.